# Texture painter brush will not paint on partial pixels. Is there a good workaround or fix?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

So I am learning how to model with a pixel art texture style and I wanted to use texture paint as shown in [this video which you should not need to watch to understand my question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQVAUaSUP-k&t=1016s). I break the rules of pixels a bit more in my model such that some of the pixels in my texture are partially hidden on the surface of the model. I can somewhat draw on them with a brush that has soft edges by drawing on their fully visible neighbors, but I want a brush with constant strength across its diameter to better facilitate my pixel art style. With this brush I cannot draw on the partially hidden pixels through that cheat anymore. Any idea how to fix this? I could just open the texture in another program but I wanna see if there is a solution in blender first.

[image: My model as it looks now. The pixels highlighted in red are the ones that my constant-falloff brush cannot paint on. Woe is me!]